# Raspberry Pi, C and Modems

Tags: c, usb, modem, pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with a SIM7600X modem attached via USB. I am writing a program in C and I need to check the signal quality of the mobile network, and also connect to the internet. Everything works well in both Minicom and Cutecom, but I cannot get it to reliably talk to the modem via C. Here's an example of my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main()
{
    FILE *modem;
    int exitflag=0;
    char buf[256];
    char *line;
    int res;
    
    modem = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB2", "r+b");
    if (modem == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open modem\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    res = fputs("\n\nAT+CSQ\n", modem);
    if (res < 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to send to modem (res = %d)\n",res);
        fclose(modem);
        return(-1);
    }
    exitflag=0;
    while (exitflag==0)
    {
        line = fgets(buf, 256, modem);
        if (line >= 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"%s",buf);
        }
        else
        {
            exitflag=1;
            fprintf(stderr,"nothing\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(modem);
    return(0);
}
```

The output can end up something like this.

```
AT+CSQ


+CSQ: 23,99



OK

AT+CS


ERROR

AT+CS


ERROR

AT+CS


ERROR

AT+CS


ERROR

AT+CS



ERROR

AT+CS



ERROR

AT+CS



ERROR

AT+CS
```

Comment: Try just `fputs("AT+CSQ\r", modem);` instead of `fputs("\n\nAT+CSQ\n", modem);` and come back to us.

Comment: Using file operations (**fopen()**, **fgets()**) on a serial terminal (i.e. **/dev/ttyUSB2**) are not ideal.  How are you going to configure the serial terminal when you have not **open()** 'd the terminal and don't have a file descriptor for **tc[gs]etattr()**?  *"The output can end up something like this..."* -- The code posted does not match the output posted.

Answer (score 0):

Most modems require `\r` instead of `\n`.

Comment: That's not correct. Actually **every modem requires (according to ETSII specification)  that commands are terminated with `\r`**. Any interpretation of `\n` as a command terminator is not compliant with the standard. What sounds strange to me is that this mistake (that should lead to a no-answer) shouldn't cause the last character cut.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni yes you are right. Simple suggestion as I was in the middle of the windows command line program development (`"\r\n"`). Amemded

Answer (score 0):

*update*
Waveshare weren't much use with this. A look through their code refers to "SIM7600AT-COMMAND" which I presume does the same as atinout, but looks for libraries in the makefile that I don't have installed on my Pi.
So, I returned to QMICLI to get information and to connect to the internet. The reason it would freeze was because I don't think I have a big enough power supply (5v @ 4a) but I have to make a new 24v to 5v connection anyway for the end use.